# Verify xml file has data past the first node in Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell, powershell-5.0

**I want to verify that an xml file has data past any first tier node.**

My .xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<[NodeName] xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <[NodeNameHere] "information here" />
</Node1>
```

The `[NodeNameHere]` and `[NodeName]` changes between files so I can't use that to test to see if there are child nodes.

So far I've tried using:

```
$xmlFile.LastChild.HasChildNodes
$xmlFile.FirstChild.HasChildNodes
```

In the above example the `LastChild` returns true while the `FirstChild` returns false. This would work, however there may be another node (not first or last) that contains data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
$xmlFile.DocumentElement.HasChildNodes
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick. Better than `$xmlFile.ChildNodes.HasChildNodes`, then checking the response for `$true`.